# Running VS 2017 Build Tools in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, batch-file, environment-variables

I dislike IDEs, so I installed the VS 2017 Build Tools so I can work via command-line.

The install went fine, and everything works out of Windows CMD, however, PowerShell is much better, and I prefer to use PS. The issue here is that according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx):

> The Visual C++ command-line tools use the PATH, TMP, INCLUDE, LIB, and LIBPATH environment variables, and may also use tool-specific environment variables. Because the values of these environment variables are specific to your installation, and can be changed by product updates or upgrades, we recommend that you use vcvarsall.bat or a Developer Command Prompt shortcut instead of setting them yourself. For information about the specific environment variables used by the compiler and linker, see CL Environment Variables and LINK Environment Variables.

I shouldn't set the Environment Variables myself, and that's fine with me, the only issue is that when I run the `vcvarsall.bat` in PS, no environment variables change. I am new to PS, so I'm guessing that `.bat` files can't alter session environment variables. If that's the case, then I can't work out of PS. As a side note, the `CL` and `LINK` variables never show up, I'll explain below.

I figured I should find out what the variables are. I `echo`ed all my variables to a text file before and after running the `batch` file, and wrote a short Java program to find anything new, or modified. These are [them](https://hastebin.com/ejotojator.txt). As you can see the `CL` and `LINK` variables are not present.

How do I solve this issue? I was thinking of writing my own `batch` file, but if the first one didn't work, why would mine? I didn't see anything on the attached MSDN page, or any links there about how to make this work for PowerShell.

Comment: The references to `CL Environment Variables` and `LINK Environment Variables` on the MSDN page you linked are **links**. Did you follow them to see what they added?

Comment: Write a batch file that 1) invokes `vcvarsall.bat`, and 2) invokes PowerShell. PowerShell will then run with the environment block prepared for it. The other way around doesn't work because PowerShell doesn't execute batch files itself -- it relies on `cmd` to do that, and as a child process, that has its own environment block that doesn't reflect on its parent.

Comment: @KenWhite Both supposedly add variables of the same name: `CL` and `_CL_` and `LINK` and `_Link_`. None of these show up, and that is what I meant.

Comment: You should use the current version of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables), where you may note it states that the CL tool uses the CL environment variable **if defined** to prepend things to commands, so if there's nothing defined it doesn't prepend things to commands.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wrote the batch file: https://hastebin.com/omeparoruc.bat but it doesn't seem to work. If I double-click it, a CMD pops up for a second, says the environment is initialised, then goes away and nothing happens. Additionally, if I run the batch file in a CMD session, it does the same as double-clicking on it, doesn't even open PS in CMD.

Comment: `CALL vcvarsall.bat`. Invoking a batch file directly ends execution of the original batch file.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you. It works. If you make that an answer, I will select and upvote it. I also tried this line to play around `start powershell`. If I do just that, PS opens in its default window, with default background, etc. If I do `start "" powershell`, it opens PS in a CMD window. Any idea why? Thanks again for your help, I was afraid I'd have to write some complicated PS script.

Comment: No, I don't know how `START` works in all its myriad ways, that might be a topic for another question. However, you can easily verify with a tool like `procexp` that `start "" powershell` still only starts PowerShell, not `cmd`. Its window just looks different. There is no such thing as a "`cmd` window", instead, both `cmd` and PowerShell use console windows (hosted by `conhost.exe`). If you really wanted to change the PowerShell title bar and it's not just academic curiosity, I'd use `$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle` from PowerShell itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a batch file that 1) invokes `vcvarsall.bat`, and 2) invokes PowerShell, like so (this one is specific to VS 2015):

```
@CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %*
@start powershell
```

`%*` allows us to pass the same arguments to this file as you would to `vcvarsall.bat`.

PowerShell will then run with the environment block prepared for it. The other way around doesn't work because PowerShell doesn't execute batch files itself -- it relies on `cmd` to do that, and as a child process, that has its own environment block that doesn't reflect on its parent.

Comment: For VS2017 Build Tools, the path to call is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`

Answer (score 3):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Invokes the specified batch file and retains any environment variable changes it makes.
.DESCRIPTION
    Invoke the specified batch file (and parameters), but also propagate any
    environment variable changes back to the PowerShell environment that
    called it.
.PARAMETER Path
    Path to a .bat or .cmd file.
.PARAMETER Parameters
    Parameters to pass to the batch file.
.EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> Invoke-BatchFile "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
    Invokes the vcvarsall.bat file.  All environment variable changes it makes will be
    propagated to the current PowerShell session.
.NOTES
    Author: Lee Holmes
#>
function Invoke-BatchFile
{
    param([string]$Path, [string]$Parameters)

    $tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    ## Store the output of cmd.exe.  We also ask cmd.exe to output
    ## the environment table after the batch file completes
    cmd.exe /c " `"$Path`" $Parameters && set " > $tempFile

    ## Go through the environment variables in the temp file.
    ## For each of them, set the variable in our local environment.
    Get-Content $tempFile | Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match "^(.*?)=(.*)$") {
            Set-Content "env:\$($matches[1])" $matches[2]
        }
        else {
            $_
        }
    }

    Remove-Item $tempFile
}

$VcVars = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat'
Invoke-BatchFile $VcVars x64
cl hello_world.cpp
```